# How can I add a banner on my wordpress in order to have it at my every post?

Tags: wordpress

I would like to add a banner/ image  below of each post of a website-wordpress in order to appear at every post of the site?

Is it possible?

Comment: for this you will have to add a custom page template and there add a slider.

Comment: and before slider show your post using WP_Query();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It is possible, If you just want to add any text then you can use admin notice plugin or If you want to display any picture you can use any kind of advertising plugin with help you to place Banner in each Post or Page.